# yq: How to change string value which looks like an array?

Tags: yq

Suppose I've the following input.yaml:

```
data:
  key1: |
    - name: valueA
    - name: valueB
```

Now I want to transform this using mikefarahs yq to output.yaml:

```
data:
  key1: |
    - name: valueC
    - name: valueD
```

My "best" approach is this:

```
yq -i e '.data.key1         |= "- name: valueC"' in.yaml
```

which results in:

```
data:
  key1: |-
    - name: valueC
```

and which is not what I want.There are at least 3 problems:

1. it is not the way how to use yq
2. it creates pipe dash (|-) not intended
3. it allows to set only the first value of the array (and remove the reminder)

Question: what is correct yq command to transform the input.yam to desired output.yaml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `.key1` is a multi-line string (note the `|`) that contains a YAML-encoded structure. You have to decode it first, make your changes, and re-encode it. You can use the update operator `|=` to operate on a subitem while keeping the overall context:

```bash
.data.key1 |= (fromyaml | .[0].name = "valueC" | .[1].name = "valueD" | toyaml)
```

```yaml
data:
  key1: |
    - name: valueC
    - name: valueD
```

Comment: Thank you ! 2 comments: 1. I updated the title of my question so it better fits to the topic. 2. Is there a way to actually remove all but the the first line of the multistring ?

Comment: It may be noted, that the fromyaml/toyaml/etc only works with the newest (?) version of yq. I just downloaded version 4.34.1 in order to get it work.

Comment: @user1240076 You can get rid of all but the first item by slicing the array starting at position 1 (which is the second after 0): `.data.key1 |= (fromyaml | .[1:] | toyaml)` (skip `toyaml` if you want to retain the array instead of the multi-line string).

Comment: @user1240076 `fromyaml` and `toyaml` were introduced in [version 4.14.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.14.1) (October 30, 2021).

Comment: ok, I stumbled over missing "e/eval" command. (eval cannot be ommited in version 4.2 which I was using). Thanks for clarification.

Comment: $ yq4.2 -V -> yq version 4.2.0
$yq4.2 '.data ' tmp.yml -> Error: unknown command ".data " for "yq"